# Adding Lines and Rectangles to Facet Plots

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to draw a similar graph shown on plotly sample page @ https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/ , under the 'Adding Lines and Rectangles to Facet Plots' section. The rectangle shade was only drawn on the first col of graphs, but I wish same shades to be seen on rest of graphs. How can it be done?

The code used from the sample is:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)
fig = px.line(df, facet_col="company", facet_col_wrap=2)
fig.add_hline(y=1, line_dash="dot",
              annotation_text="Jan 1, 2018 baseline",
              annotation_position="bottom right")

fig.add_vrect(x0="2018-09-24", x1="2018-12-18", col=1,
              annotation_text="decline", annotation_position="top left",
              fillcolor="green", opacity=0.25, line_width=0)
fig.show()
```

Though I already provided my finding below and didn't delete my post because wishing to share with other new plotly users with similar confusion, there is still one 'experienced' person from the community vote -1 for this post. However, I will continue to share. :)

Answer (score 1):

Realizing the code from the sample specified col=1, which causing the shade only appear on one col of graphs.